# jQuery checkbox manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, checkbox, html-table

I have a list of checkboxes, looking like this:

```
<table>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label>Bla</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Bla Sub 1</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Bla Sub 2</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Bla Sub 3</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Bla Sub 4</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Bla Sub 5</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Bla Sub 6</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> Blub</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Blub Sub 1</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Blub Sub 2</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Blub Sub 3</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> + Blub Sub 4</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> Derp</label></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /> <label> etc...</label></td></tr>
</table>
```

So, I want to enable a "select sub categories" function to such a list. Unfortunately to ASP.NET's messed up ID-rendering, I cant call the categories by their IDs or Names, so I'd have to read out the contents of each node and un/select all check boxes that start with `+`.

So, if the user selects `Bla`, all sublists `+ Bla Sub #` should also be selected, and vise versa.

How is this possible? I use jQuery, so it shouldn't be that hard, but I can't quite get a start on how to check the lists contents...

Comment: I forgot to mention, that all labels and checkboxes are in a table... Thanks Microsoft, thats how you create a list?...

Comment: Florian, please do not use swear words in any content that you post on StackOverflow. Your question will be edited to remove the swearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('ul li:not(:contains("+"))').click(function(
 var current = $(this), check;
 check = (current.attr('checked') ^ true);
 $('ul li:contains("'+current.text()+'") checkbox').attr('checked',check);
}
```

I haven't tested it though. It certainly should give you an idea of what is required. Comment if you've any questions at all.

Comment: It does, somehow, work, but not as intended... I broke your function down and the main problem seems to be the iteration, to *check all following boxes that containt a "+"* and the translation of that into jQuery :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a class to these sub checkboxes in ASP.net, and then iterate over them using $('.className').

Comment: Problem is, the list is generated automatically using `DataBind()` and `DataSource()` on a table of the database, so I can't manipulate the list-item itself :-/

Answer (score 0):

This will make is so when you check "Bla"  all "+ Bla *" will get checked:

```
$('label:not(:contains(+))').prev(':checkbox').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('label:contains("'+$this.next('label').text()+'")').prev(':checkbox')
    .attr('checked',$this.is(':checked'));
});
```